# GDB does not break on a read access to an address caught by PIN

Tags: debugging, gdb, intel-pin

I've captured a read memory trace (i.e. addresses of all read accesses) of a program-run by Intel PIN, [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) was off. I can capture it several times and the trace is still exactly the same.

Then I take an address from the trace (a specific address I am interested in), set a watchpoint in GDB by `rwatch *0x7fffe309e643` but GDB does not notice the access. I'm doing this in the same terminal where the trace has been taken so it should access the same addresses; when I capture it then again, the trace is still very the same.

Do you have any ideas or hints why GDB does not catch it?

I have to note that the access very likely happens within a (C++) structure loaded from a Boost serialization and that the code has been compiled with `-g3 -O1` flags (`-O1` is really crucial for other reasons but a minimal example showed me that GDB breaks correctly even with `-O1`).

**UPDATE:**

As suggested, I tried PIN debugger (which actually utilizes GDB) but there is some problem with watchpoints. To present this problem, I made a minimal example.

```
int main()
{
  unsigned char i = 4;
  i++;
  i = 3;
  return 0;
}
```

I acquired a read memory trace with PIN and chose `0x7fffffffd89f` (or similar) as the address of interest. Then I started PIN debugger and GDB in parallel terminals and connected GDB to PIN (`(gdb) target remote :57946`, as suggested by PIN). In GDB I set watchpoint `(gdb) rwatch *0x7fffffffd89f` and started execution but I get

```
Continuing.
Warning:
Could not insert hardware watchpoint 1.
Could not insert hardware breakpoints:
You may have requested too many hardware breakpoints/watchpoints.
```

even though I only inserted a single watchpoint. I also tried to explicitly disable hardware breakpoints by `set can-use-hw-watchpoints 0` but then it ran for an hour with no result and no processor load so I killed it.

Is there any other way how to set a functional watchpoint at a specific address when GDB is connected to PIN debugger? Note that there is no such problem with standalone GDB.

I use GDB 7.7.1, PIN 2.14-71313 and GCC 4.4.7, running Ubuntu 14.04.

The original problem would be likely solved then.

Comment: Try adding appropriate type: `rwatch *(yourstruct*)0x7fffe309e643`.

Answer (score 1):

From pin [user guide](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/71313/Pin/html/index.html#MEMORY):

```
The "pin" Executable (Launcher)

The kit's root directory contains a "pin" executable. This is a 32-bit
launcher, used for launching Pin in 32 and 64 bit modes. The launcher
sets up the environment to find the libraries supplied with the kit.
```

It is likely that the environment is different when running `pinbin`, and therefore stack addresses will also be different (`0x7fffe309e643` looks like a possible stack address) even without ASLR.

Your best bet is probably to use Pin [application debugging](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/71313/Pin/html/index.html#APPDEBUG) interface.

Comment: I tried but unfortunately there is another issue, see my update.